# JTable cell value change listener

Tags: swing, jtable, listener

Which listener can be used to react to the event of JTable cell value change? I tried using TableModelListener but either I got something wrong, or this listener doesn't react on changing the contents of a cell.

I need to act either to changing the content of a cell or to cell losing focus. What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: something is wrong with your model implementation (or its usage) - it must notify _always_ on change. TableModelListener is the way to go

Comment: Indeed, this was the case. One of the table update methods replaced the model and listener was attached to old model. Thank you for assuring me which to look.

Answer (score 7):

```
class extends JTable {
```

....
(inside contructor)

```
addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            if (isEditing())
                processEditingStarted();
            else
                processEditingStopped();
        }
    }
});
```

... (end constructor)

```
protected void processEditingStopped() {
    System.out.println("save " + editingRow + ":" + editingColumn);
}

protected void processEditingStarted() {
    System.out.println("edit " + editingRow + ":" + editingColumn);
    if (editRow > -1 && editColumn > -1)
        oldValue = (String) model.getValueAt(editRow, editColumn);
}
```

}

more details here: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/

Comment: ehh ... no (incorrectly copied from Rob's suggestion ;-) Which in the general case isn't the best thing to do anyway.

Comment: it's not copied it's interpreted

Comment: the emphasis is on _incorrect_ (not copied) - carefully compare the details :-)

Comment: +1 for link: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/ it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to react to values changing is to customize a table model and react to `setValueAt()`.

If you're looking to make sure edits "**stick**" when it loses focus, call this on the table.

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: Spot on, I used:

`list.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Column: " + e.getColumn() + " Row: " + e.getFirstRow());
   }
  });`

It gives me the column and row edited, although it doesn't detect if a change occured only that the cell was edited. So you'll need to check against the original value somehow. But this saved me messing with my already overly complex JTable constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Bill, it maybe easier to "watch" the model rather than the JTable, I used this and was able to track changes by column and row:

```
list.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Column: " + e.getColumn() + " Row: " + e.getFirstRow());
            }
        });
```

As mentioned in my comment to their answer, it doesn't detect if a change occured only that the cell was edited. So you'll need to check against the original value somehow. But this saved me messing with my JTable constructor.